# Обработка формы в php

Tags: php

Как сделать в php чтобы при нажатии одной кнопки radio появлялся файл загрузки.
Т.е. есть форма

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Message<input name="fp" type="radio">
Posting<input name="fp" type="radio">"><br>
Ваше имя:<br />
<input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Ваш E-mail:<br />
<input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Сообщение:<br />
<textarea name="msg" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea><br />
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000">
Send this IMG: <input name="userfile" type="file"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Добавить!" />

</form>
```

и чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на Posting появлялся файл загрузки, а когда Message его не было.?

Comment: javascript + css вам в помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откопал скрипт который писал года три назад)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = LoadFile;
function LoadFile() {
var FileInput = document.getElementById('file');
var FileName = document.getElementById('filename');
var LoadButton = document.getElementById('loadbutton');
var OpenFile = FileInput.value;
    reWin = /.*\\(.*)/;
    OpenFile = OpenFile.replace(reWin, "$1");
    reUnix = /.*\/(.*)/;
    OpenFile = OpenFile.replace(reUnix, "$1");
FileName.innerHTML = OpenFile;

if(OpenFile == '') {
    LoadButton.style.display = 'none';
}else{
    LoadButton.style.display = 'block';
}
}
</script>
<style>
input.file { height: 30px; width: 100px;  opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity:0; }
.button { cursor: pointer; }
</style>
</head>
</html>
<body>
<div style="border: 1px solid; width: 100px;">//для этого дива нарисовать красивую кнопочку и пристроить как background через css
<form action="/" method="post" name="fileform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input size="1" type="file" name="loadfile" id="file" class="file" onchange="LoadFile();" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="filename"></div>
<span class="button" id="loadbutton" onclick="document.fileform.submit();" >Загрузить</span>
</body>
```

**Сделать под себя** красивости и можно юзать!